# ¿Cómo obtener datos con JavaSccript de otra web que tiene coordenadas y almacenarlas en un Json?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

El punto es que necesito obtener todos los datos “coordenadas”, de una web y almacenarlos en un json u objeto, para trabajar con ellos y mapearlos en google maps API3 , desde ya muchas gracias.
Esta es la url de la pagina de la que quiero obtener esos datos. [cobertura.tigo.com.bo](http://cobertura.tigo.com.bo/hfc/hfc.dat)

> esta en una etiqueta `<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">`
>   576741},{"x":-17.434268151,"y":-66.153574243},{"x":-17.434248234,"y":-66.153152066},{"x":-17.433963108,"y":-66.153152193},{"x":-17.433958917,"y":-66.152846578},{"x":-17.434070669,"y":-66.152843763},{"x":-17.434065538,"y":-66.152678611},{"x":-17.434198438,"y":-66.152453076},{"x":-17.435292787,"y":-66.153225921},{"x":-17.435590562,"y":-66.153071301},{"x":-17.436872834,"y":-66.152097509},{"x":-17.436974719,"y":-66.152567349},{"x":-17.436728926,"y":-66.152650887},{"x":-17.436868475,"y":-66.153364768},{"x":-17.436882999,"y":-66.153673323},{"x":-17.436547287,"y":-66.153690331},{"x":-17.436555066,"y":-66.153844252},{"x":-17.437067193,"y":-66.153987898},{"x":-17.437113360,"y":-66.154500350},{"x":-17.436995166,"y":-66.154636971},{"x":-17.436788617,"y":-66.154634696},{"x":-17.436793537,"y":-66.154894398},{"x":-17.436913311,"y":-66.155092193},{"x":-17.436915624,"y":-66.155370813},{"x":-17.436492948,"y":-66.155357597},{"x":-17.436492953,"y":-66.155485647},{"x":-17.436614271,"y":-66.155484668},{"x":-17.436607866,"y":-66.155612605},{"x":-17.436722366,"y":-66.155710990},{"x":-17.436718338,"y":-66.155907582},{"x":-17.437081619,"y":-66.155905399},{"x":-17.437097568,"y":-66.156016662},{"x":-17.437836349,"y":-66.155972809},{"x":-17.437964226,"y":-66.155972277},{"x":-17.437968235,"y":-66.156179005},{"x":-17.437845544,"y":-66.156327981},{"x":-17.437851103,"y":-66.156557619},{"x":-17.438016843,"y":-66.156554989},{"x":-17.438011194,"y":-66.156671157},{"x":-17.438165560,"y":-66.156668724},{"x":-17.438167285,"y":-66.157027787},{"x":-17.438038049,"y":-66.157019723}]},
>   ,{"id":"CBB043","code":"CBB043","name":"","territory":"","city":"","dealer":"","value":"7","alt_code":"0","amount":"656","polygon":[{"x":-17.440130029,"y":-66.160748905},{"x":-17.439815949,"y":-66.161638498},{"x":-17.439298940,"y":-66.162386847},{"x":-17.438093092,"y":-66.162144816},{"x":-17.434614495,"y":-66.161271558},{"x":-17.434683427,"y":-66.160857781},{"x":-17.434607637,"y":-66.160838309},{"x":-17.434651689,"y":-66.160652226},{"x":-17.434299416,"y":-66.160561719},{"x":-17.434344402,"y":-66.160232494},{"x":-17.434397882,"y":-66.160202758},{"x":-17.434455395,"y":-66.160030115},{"x":-17.433541084,"y":-66.159838838},{"x":-17.433591889,"y":-66.159472400},{"x":-17.432962990,"y":-66.159370947},{"x":-17.432869530,"y":-66.159254050},{"x":-17.432875237,"y":-66.159104960},{"x":-17.432925861,"y":-66.159086806},{"x":-17.432928221,"y":-66.158977529},{"x":-17.433489234,"y":-66.158971983},{"x":-17.433557266,"y":-66.158502808},{"x":-17.433745642,"y":-66.158509424},{"x":-17.433750541,"y":-66.158298661},{"x":-17.434734405,"y":-66.158289876},{"x":-17.434735313,"y":-66.158400207},{"x":-17.434906740,"y":-66.158411543},{"x":-17.435186854,"y":-66.158465803},{"x":-17.435185932,"y":-66.158331540},{"x":-17.435327791,"y":-66.158328624},{"x":-17.435341240,"y":-66.157846279},{"x":-17.434704348,"y":-66.157827008},{"x":-17.434686396,"y":-66.157636749},{"x":-17.434830328,"y":-66.157622010},{"x":-17.434845573,"y":-66.157413771},{"x":-17.434766478,"y":-66.157398333},{"x":-17.434760410,"y":-66.157180509},{"x":-17.435160104,"y":-66.157168425},{"x":-17.435362823,"y":-66.157192217},{"x":-17.435400689,"y":-66.157329894},{"x":-17.435886172,"y":-66.157316930},{"x":-17.435896375,"y":-66.156625095},{"x":-17.436367315,"y":-66.156577174},{"x":-17.436360442,"y":-66.157056026},{"x":-17.436526723,"y":-66.157130135},{"x":-17.436587958,"y":-66.157632558},{"x":-17.436517896,"y":-66.157689291},{"x":-17.436513976,"y":-66.157785078},{"x":-17.436707281,"y":-66.157793663},{"x":-17.436739417,"y":-66.158005237},{"x":-17.436909849,"y":-66.158018814},{"x":-17.436921056,"y":-66.157866132},{"x":-17.437106289,"y":-66.157871483},{"x":-17.437115916,"y":-66.157973822},{"x":-17.437165951,"y":-66.157966711},{"x":-17.437200676,"y":-66.158231883},{"x":-17.436989647,"y":-66.158261875},{"x":-17.437012981,"y":-66.158557051},{"x":-17.436950904,"y":-66.158563330},{"x":-17.436983295,"y":-66.158910914},{"x":-17.437077002,"y":-66.158932812},{"x":-17.437102709,"y":-66.158812542},{"x":-17.437759318,"y":-66.158777941},{"x":-17.437751138,"y":-66.158555783},{"x":-17.438070642,"y":-66.158543014},{"x":-17.438070007,"y":-66.158325969},{"x":-17.437988135,"y":-66.158347590},{"x":-17.437985818,"y":-66.158250012},{"x":-17.438166638,"y":-66.158245352},{"x":-17.438376945,"y":-66.158143417},{"x":-17.438430821,"y":-66.158137534},{"x":-17.438454147,"y":-66.158369390},{"x":-17.438654072,"y":-66.158368837},{"x":-17.438674373,"y":-66.158313021},{"x":-17.438778593,"y":-66.158311678},{"x":-17.438857029,"y":-66.158472523},{"x":-17.439106512,"y":-66.158470350},{"x":-17.439111629,"y":-66.159108037},{"x":-17.439033861,"y":-66.159134049},{"x":-17.439095262,"y":-66.159916644},{"x":-17.439314373,"y":-66.159956626},{"x":-17.439445622,"y":-66.160046964},{"x":-17.439636543,"y":-66.160043784},{"x":-17.439638203,"y":-66.160151898},{"x":-17.439854242,"y":-66.160181759},{"x":-17.440140967,"y":-66.160138070},{"x":-17.440131210,"y":-66.160752779},{"x":-17.440130029,"y":-66.160748905}]},{"id":"CBB044","code":"CBB044","name":"","territory":"","city":"","dealer":"","value":"5","alt_code":"0","amount":"614","polygon":[{"x":-17.440219137,"y":-66.160496967},{"x":-17.440131667,"y":-66.160747966},{"x":-17.440140967,"y":-66.160138070},{"x":-17.439854242,"y":-66.160181759},{"x":-17.439638203,"y":-66.160151898},{"x":-17.439636543,"y":-66.160043784},{"x":-17.439445622,"y":-66.160046964},{"x":-17.439314373,"y":-66.159956626},{"x":-17.439095262,"y":-66.159916644},{"x":-17.439033861,"y":-66.159134049},{"x":-17.439111629,"y":-66.159108037},{"x":-17.439106512,"y":-66.158470350},{"x":-17.438857029,"y":-66.158472523},{"x":-17.438778593,"y":-66.158311678},{"x":-17.438674373,"y":-66.158313021},{"x":-17.438654072,"y":-66.158368837},{"x":-17.438454147,"y":-66.158369390},{"x":-17.438431374,"y":-66.158143034},{"x":-17.438166638,"y":-66.158245352},{"x":-17.437987335,"y":-66.158246899},{"x":-17.438010404,"y":-66.158341709},{"x":-17.438070007,"y":-66.158325969},{"x":-17.438070642,"y":-66.158543014},{"x":-17.437761207,"y":-66.158540344},{"x":-17.437759318,"y":-66.158777941},{"x":-17.437102709,"y":-66.158812542},{"x":-17.437076822,"y":-66.158932770},{"x":-17.436983295,"y":-66.158910914},{"x":-17.436950398,"y":-66.158557901},{"x":-17.437012981,"y":-66.158557051},{"x":-17.437008947,"y":-66.158234485},{"x":-17.437200676,"y":-66.158231883},{"x":-17.437169982,"y":-66.157997493},{"x":-17.437115916,"y":-66.157973822},{"x":-17.437106289,"y":-66.157871483},{"x":-17.437009418,"y":-66.157873171},{"x":-17.437006879,"y":-66.157270338},{"x":-17.437191540,"y":-66.157267830},{"x":-17.437311689,"y":-66.157344871},{"x":-17.437396085,"y":-66.157309917},{"x":-17.437394876,"y":-66.157197679},{"x":-17.438032368,"y":-66.157186034},{"x":-17.438038158,"y":-66.157018082},{"x":-17.438168202,"y":-66.157029846},{"x":-17.438162911,"y":-66.156668371},{"x":-17.438012537,"y":-66.156670280},{"x":-17.438013883,"y":-66.156552501},{"x":-17.437852267,"y":-66.156556139},{"x":-17.437847577,"y":-66.156330019},{"x":-17.437969395,"y":-66.156183145},{"x":-17.437966171,"y":-66.155971169},{"x":-17.437829110,"y":-66.155973431},{"x":-17.437827174,"y":-66.155718067},{"x":-17.437700677,"y":-66.155603201},{"x":-17.437706012,"y":-66.155428397},{"x":-17.438006883,"y":-66.155390856},{"x":-17.437983702,"y":-66.154559853},{"x":-17.438294416,"y":-66.154513995},{"x":-17.438428919,"y":-66.154586258},{"x":-17.438432549,"y":-66.154821281},{"x":-17.439082307,"y":-66.154825877},{"x":-17.439078984,"y":-66.154701937},{"x":-17.439527455,"y":-66.154713005},{"x":-17.439529107,"y":-66.154766001},{"x":-17.440145412,"y":-66.154750977},{"x":-17.440128636,"y":-66.154237834},{"x":-17.440259848,"y":-66.154246583},{"x":-17.440363327,"y":-66.154096498},{"x":-17.440400556,"y":-66.153798833},{"x":-17.440595980,"y":-66.153727760},{"x":-17.440543643,"y":-66.153608750},{"x":-17.441164286,"y":-66.153392124},{"x":-17.441192467,"y":-66.153059720},{"x":-17.441479301,"y":-66.152948082},{"x":-17.441668036,"y":-66.153474397},{"x":-17.441988519,"y":-66.153380637},{"x":-17.441536443,"y":-66.156296268},{"x":-17.441342743,"y":-66.157829346},{"x":-17.440219137,"y":-66.160496967}]},........................

Y esta es una imagen de la misma [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo mediante ajax, por ejemplo de la siguiente forma:

```
var url='http://cobertura.tigo.com.bo/hfc/hfc.dat',
    httpR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpR.open('GET', url, true);
    httpR.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (httpR.readyState == 4) {
        if(httpR.status == 200) {

            var json = JSON.parse(httpR.responseText);

            console.log(json);


         }
    }
};


httpR.send(null);
```

Comment: Gracias PlayerWet pero me encontre con esto   [Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://cobertura.tigo.com.bo/hfc/hfc.dat (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').] creo que de algun modo requiere una confirmacion. Saludos